# How to copy an item of type [Int: LearningItem]()

Tags: swift

I have a variable with type

```
 var items = [Int:[LearningItem]]()
```

How can I copy that to another variable? I tried using Dictionary(items) but I get an error `Argument type '[Int : [LearningItem]]' expected to be an instance of a class or class-constrained type`

Thanks for the help!

Comment: How about `var items2 = items`, to `...copy items to another variable`

Comment: What are you trying to do, is it a simple copy or a deep copy? What is `LearningItem`, a struct or a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As workingdog commented, it's easy to make a shallow copy:  see the first comment under your question.

If you're looking for a way of making deep copies, the function in the example below should work **as long as your** `LearningItem` **implementation's properties are all themselves primitive or value types**.  (In the case that any properties of the class/struct are *reference* types, making a true deep copy would be more complicated and beyond the scope of this answer.)

The copying function here will work regardless of whether your `LearningItem` is a `Class` or a `Struct`.  Below are implementations of `LearningItem` as both a `Class` and a `Struct` for demonstration purposes, as well as all code from `ViewController.swift`.  Everything else is the same as the default project template from Xcode.

```
import Foundation

class LearningItem_C {
    var title: String
    var grade: Int
    var subject: String
    
    init(title: String, grade: Int, subject: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.grade = grade
        self.subject = subject
        LearningItem_C.allInstances.append(self)
    }
    
    static var allInstances: [LearningItem_C] = []
}

struct LearningItem_S {
    var title: String
    var grade: Int
    var subject: String
    
    init(title: String, grade: Int, subject: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.grade = grade
        self.subject = subject
        LearningItem_S.allInstances.append(self)
    }
    
    static var allInstances: [LearningItem_S] = []
}
```

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    // A dictionary with keys of type Int and values of type [LearningItem class instance] array
    var item_C = [Int: [LearningItem_C]]()
    // A dictionary with keys of type Int and values of type [LearningItem struct] array
    var item_S = [Int: [LearningItem_S]]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Add key:value pairs to the dictionaries declared above, so that they are no longer empty
        item_C[1] = [LearningItem_C(title: "Intro Quiz", grade: 6, subject: "Algebra"), LearningItem_C(title: "Advanced Quiz", grade: 8, subject: "Algebra II")]
        item_C[2] = [LearningItem_C(title: "Rivers Test", grade: 10, subject: "Geography"), LearningItem_C(title: "Mountains Test", grade: 10, subject: "Geography")]
        
        item_S[1] = [LearningItem_S(title: "Pre-Test", grade: 3, subject: "Math"), LearningItem_S(title: "Post-Test", grade: 3, subject: "Math")]
        item_S[2] = [LearningItem_S(title: "Paleolithic Quiz", grade: 8, subject: "History"), LearningItem_S(title: "Neolithic Quiz", grade: 8, subject: "History")]
        
        print("Before making any copies, there are \(LearningItem_C.allInstances.count) instances stored in the LearningItem Class' static array, and \(LearningItem_S.allInstances.count) instances in the LearningItem Struct's static array.\n")
        
        let class_deepCopy = generateDeepCopy(of: item_C, withItemType: "Class") as! [Int: [LearningItem_C]]
        // Because of the way structs work (changing a struct's property throws out the whole thing and replaces it with a completely new struct),
        // this must be assigned to a *var*, not a *let* constant, or else you'll get an error when you try to make changes to the deep copy below.
        var struct_deepCopy = generateDeepCopy(of: item_S, withItemType: "Struct") as! [Int: [LearningItem_S]]
        
        // Changes to the copy will now affect only the copy, and not the original:
        class_deepCopy[1]![0].title = "NEW TITLE"
        class_deepCopy[2]![1].grade = 1000
        
        print("Now, after making changes to the CLASS deep copy:\n-------------------------------------------------")
        for k in item_C.keys {
            for i in 0...1 {
                print("Original value at [\(k)]:  \(item_C[k]![i].title), \(item_C[k]![i].grade), \(item_C[k]![i].subject)")
                print("Deep copy's value at [\(k)]:  \(class_deepCopy[k]![i].title), \(class_deepCopy[k]![i].grade), \(class_deepCopy[k]![i].subject)\n")
            }
        }
        print("You can see that new items have been added to the Class' static array: its length is now \(LearningItem_C.allInstances.count)\n")
        print("-------------------------------------------------\n")
        
        // Demonstrate the same principle, with the struct version:
        struct_deepCopy[1]![1].title = "CHANGED TITLE"
        struct_deepCopy[2]![0].subject = "underwater basketweaving"
        
        print("And, after making changes to the STRUCT deep copy:\n------------------------------------------------")
        for k in item_S.keys {
            for i in 0...1 {
                print("Original value at [\(k)]:  \(item_S[k]![i].title), \(item_S[k]![i].grade), \(item_S[k]![i].subject)")
                print("Deep copy's value at [\(k)]:  \(struct_deepCopy[k]![i].title), \(struct_deepCopy[k]![i].grade), \(struct_deepCopy[k]![i].subject)\n")
            }
        }
        print("You can see that new items have also been added to the Struct's static array: its length is now \(LearningItem_S.allInstances.count)\n")
    }
    
    // Caveat:  This only yields a truly 'deep' copy if all of the LearningItem class/struct's parameters are primitive or value types!
    // If your implementation of the LearningItem has any -reference type- parameters, this method is *not* an adequate solution.
    func generateDeepCopy(of dict: [Int: [Any]], withItemType: String) -> [Int: [Any]] {
        var output: [Int: [Any]] = [:]
        for k in dict.keys {
            output[k] = []
            for v in dict[k]! {
                if withItemType == "Class" {
                    let v2 = v as! LearningItem_C
                    output[k]!.append(LearningItem_C(title: v2.title, grade: v2.grade, subject: v2.subject))
                } else {
                    let v2 = v as! LearningItem_S
                    output[k]!.append(LearningItem_S(title: v2.title, grade: v2.grade, subject: v2.subject))
                }
            }
        }
        return output
    }
}
```