# What really happens "behind the scenes" when you copy a struct?

Tags: swift, struct, init, value-type, reference-type

In Swift, the `Struct` is a value type, while the `Class` is a reference type.  So, two different variables cannot point to the same underlying `struct` instance, while they **can** point to the same instance of a `class`.  This means that making a "shallow copy" of a class instance by simply assigning it to a new variable means that changing the instance via the second variable is reflected when accessing the same instance via the first variable.  This is exactly what you'd expect, and works the same as in other programming languages I'm familiar with (like the `Object` in JavaScript).

But, since `Struct` is *not* a reference type, you'd also expect that there would be no such thing as a "shallow copy" of a `struct` instance - every time you assign a new variable to a `struct`, you should get a separate, new instance with the same value.  Changing one of a `struct`'s properties, unlike for an instance of a class, discards the original `struct` and replaces it with a new one, since `struct`s are also immutable.  Presumably, this means that every time you copy or change a `struct`, a new instance is created at that time.  When a new instance of the `struct` is created, I would expect the `init` method to run.  This doesn't actually happen, though!

In the code sample below, I copy the same kind of `struct` both with the "shallow copy" method and with the "deep copy" technique which I would use on instances of a class.  My belief at the time of writing the code was that the result of both methods of copying a `struct` would be exactly the same.  However, only the "deep copy" method causes the `struct`'s `init` method to run, while the "shallow copy" does not.  This is evident from inspecting the length of the static array property inside the `struct` after both attempts at copying instances.  The length increases after making "deep copies," but **not** after making shallow copies!

Making changes to the "shallow copy" still **does not** cause the changes to be reflected in the original `struct`-containing variable though.  This *does* reflect what I would expect to happen based on `struct`s being an immutable value type.

So, my question is:  How exactly are new structs created when an existing struct is copied (vs. when the constructor is explicitly called), and why doesn't it cause the `init` method to run?

MCVE demonstrating the unexpected outcome:

```
import Foundation

struct TestStruct {
    var name: String
    var value: Int

    init(name: String, value: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
        TestStruct.allInstances.append(self)
    }
    
    static var allInstances: [TestStruct] = []
}
```

and

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var structs = [TestStruct(name: "First", value: 1), TestStruct(name: "Second", value: 2)]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("We started with \(TestStruct.allInstances.count) instances in the static array")
        
        var structsCopy: [TestStruct] = []
        for s in structs {
            structsCopy.append(s)
        }
        print("Now there are \(TestStruct.allInstances.count) instances in the static array")
        
        var structsDeepCopy: [TestStruct] = []
        for s in structs {
            structsDeepCopy.append(TestStruct(name: s.name, value: s.value))
        }
        print("Now there are \(TestStruct.allInstances.count) instances in the static array")
        
        print("But, structsCopy isn't a shallow copy, because changing it doesn't change the original array:")
        structsCopy[0].name = "NEW NAME"
        print("structs[0] still has .name \(structs[0].name), while structsCopy[0].name is now \(structsCopy[0].name)")
        
        print("After making changes to a struct in the first copy, there are still just \(TestStruct.allInstances.count) instances in the static array, not 5")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Copying" a struct, by assigning it to a variable or passing it to a function, doesn't call a user-written `init`. Instead, it copies each member individually, which can be a literal copy (e.g. for the `Int`-typed property) or a retain operation (e.g. for the `String`-typed property).

That kind of "allInstances" list only makes sense for reference types such as classes. For value types, such as structs, it's impossible for that array to contain the same value as the function you created it from -- you're copying `self` to pass it to `TestStruct.allInstances.append(self)`. (Because of this, copying *can't* call a user-written initializer in the general case. It's very easy to accidentally end up with infinite recursion.) If you need an allInstances list like this, you must use a reference type -- and, to prevent memory leaks, it should probably be a list of weak references rather than a literal `[MyClass]`.

If you want value semantics -- you can't mutate a reference someone else holds -- while still being a reference type to support the allInstances list, you need to make it an immutable class like `NSString` or `NSArray` (but not `NSMutableString` or `NSMutableArray`).

Comment: Thank you for your excellent answer: that was exactly what I wanted to know!  If you're wondering, the question only came up in the context of writing a type-agnostic function that works with *either* classes or structs - otherwise I would never write something like the initializer in my example.  If you're curious, here is the post that inspired this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76262624/how-to-copy-an-item-of-type-int-learningitem/76266639#76266639